# Complete the PrintTicTacToe function with parameters horiz_char and vert_char that prints a tic-tac-toe board with the characters as follows

Tags: python

Complete the PrintTicTacToe function with parameters horiz_char and vert_char that prints a tic-tac-toe board with the characters as follows.

```
def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char, vert_char):
    # FIXME: complete function to print game board
    return
```

Ex: `print_tic_tac_toe('~', '!')` prints:

[image: Screen shot of the questions and example output]

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char, vert_char):
    a = 'x ' + vert_char + ' x ' + vert_char + ' x'
    b = ((horiz_char + ' ')*4 + horiz_char)
    print((a +'\n' + b+'\n') * 2 + a)
print_tic_tac_toe('~', '!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve this problem with loops, but I think that this is the simplest solution:

```
def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char, vert_char):
    a = "x" + vert_char + "x" + vert_char + "x"
    b = horiz_char*5
    print((a+"\n"+b+"\n")*2+a)
    
print_tic_tac_toe('~', '!')
```

Comment: Thank you! 

It seems something is off.

Your output
x~x~x
!!!!!
x~x~x
!!!!!
x~x~x

Expected output
x ! x ! x
~ ~ ~ ~ ~
x ! x ! x
~ ~ ~ ~ ~
x ! x ! x

like maybe I need to figure out how to swap the variables.

Comment: Here is a link to an image of the result. https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:1d41fe74-200e-4c32-b92f-bc2c8273f421

Comment: 'code'
def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char, vert_char):
    a = "x " + vert_char + " x " + vert_char + " x"
    b = horiz_char*5
    print((a+"\n"+b+"\n")*2+a)

print_tic_tac_toe('~', '!')
'code'

Comment: Image of my tweaks. I still seem to be missing some of the "padding" 

https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:4c14e6aa-9d9b-48b1-9038-0fb204167683

Comment: This is what I ended at. Thank you for the help @drip
<code> def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char, vert_char):
    a = "x " + vert_char + " x " + vert_char + " x"
    b = horiz_char  + " " + horiz_char  + " " + horiz_char  + " " +  horiz_char  + " " + horiz_char
    print((a+"\n"+b+"\n")*2+a)

 print_tic_tac_toe('~', '!') 
</code>

Comment: sorry, `vert_char` and `horiz_char` were mixed up, above code now works as expected